# How to print a new line after a certain character limit

Tags: python

I am trying to make a mini connect 4 board with 6 columns and 7 rows

I am looking for an output like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 
7 8 9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18
19 20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29 30
```

and so on to 42.

I am trying to make this in one list. I started off on the right track like this

```
board = []
for i in range (1,43):
    board.append(i)
```

I understand all the numbers that I need are in there but I do not know how to break up the list so that it prints a new line every 6 numbers like the example I showed.

Comment: In the eaxmple you posted the last three lines only have 5 characters. If that was not the case you might have identified the pattern with the mod6. In short, you can check the mod6 of `i` and when it is 0, do `print()`

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Answer (score 1):

For your board to look beautiful and not just correct, you would need some formatting as well.

**You can get both using the following:**

```
board = []
for i in range(1,43):
    board.append(i)
    print('{:>4}'.format(i), end='')
    if i % 6 == 0:
        print()

 #  1   2   3   4   5   6
 #  7   8   9  10  11  12
 # 13  14  15  16  17  18
 # 19  20  21  22  23  24
 # 25  26  27  28  29  30
 # 31  32  33  34  35  36
 # 37  38  39  40  41  42
```

As you can see i am suppressing the default end character of `print()` which is the newline by specifying `end=''`. Instead, whenever `i % 6 == 0` (`%` is mod by the way) a newline is printed by calling an empty `print()`. As for the formatting you can take a look at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html).

And to make everything more user-friendly i would wrap it in a function

```
def build_board(cols, rows, sp=2):
    board = []
    l = len(str(cols * rows)) + sp
    for i in range(1, cols * rows + 1):
        board.append(i)
        print('{0:>{1}}'.format(i, l), end='')
        if i % cols == 0:
            print()
    return board

build_board(8, 17, 3)

#         1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
#         9    10    11    12    13    14    15    16
#        17    18    19    20    21    22    23    24
#        25    26    27    28    29    30    31    32
#       ...
#       121   122   123   124   125   126   127   128
#       129   130   131   132   133   134   135   136
```

Answer (score 1):

```
board = []
for i in range(1,43):
    board.append(i)
    if i % 6 == 0:
        print(board[i-6:i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a two-dimensional board?  If so you could use list comprehension:

```
board = [[6*j+i for i in range(1,7)] for j in range(7)]
```

And print the contents like so (using python3):

```
for row in board:
    for column in row:
        print(column, end=' ')
    print()


1 2 3 4 5 6 
7 8 9 10 11 12 
13 14 15 16 17 18 
19 20 21 22 23 24 
25 26 27 28 29 30 
31 32 33 34 35 36 
37 38 39 40 41 42
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach.

```
import numpy as np

# convert 1D vector into 2D array
data = np.array(board).reshape(6, 7)
print '\n'.join(''.join(str(col)+' ' for col in row) for row in data)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using python 2.x, you can do like this, based on the EV. Kounis solution :

```
board = []
for i in range (1,43):
    board.append(i)
    if i%6 == 0 :print board[i-6:]
```

If Board is already created and you just have to print it, you can do like that :

```
for i in range(1,8) :print board[:i*6][(i-1)*6:]
```

(board[25:] means board without 25 first values, and
 board[:25] means 25 first values of board)